# start-process in Powershell closes Window automatically after execution is complete

Tags: powershell, process, window

I find that if I start a process by `start-process` in powershell , the new window will be closed automatically after execution complete , is it possible to keep it waiting for my further command to close?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try passing `-noexit` as a parameter to `powershell.exe` when you start it.

Answer (score 7):

you mean start a command prompt? right? if so, hope following script could be helpful

```
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c','echo test' # auto close
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/k','echo test' # keep waiting
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get what I need (open powershell as administrator in a specific location), assembling this way:

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit -command ""& {Set-Location D:\YourPath}""" -Verb runAs
exit
```

Start-process: will start powershell with Args, to not exit and open at a specific location and will call administrative privileges.
Exit> this will exit the first window that will open.